# I am getting a TypeError after adding TemplateView to my views folder

Tags: python, django

I am getting a TypeError after adding TemplateView to my views folder.
I've done a test project earlier and it worked pretty fine.I am a beginner in django

````
#views.py
```python
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomeResponse(TemplateView):
   template_name = 'home.html'

#urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.HomeResponse, name='blog_name'),
]
```


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XpRZ.png
````

Comment: post your url also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.HomeResponse.as_view(), name='blog_name'),
]
```

This shall work, you should access CBV's by calling `as_view()` method on them.